# Using SQL variable twice throws error. "Must Be Unique Witin Query Batch or Stored Procedure"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a tickets opened vs resolved per week gadget that reports back as far as the number of days that the user supplies.

My problem is that powergadgets (the gadget make I am using) throws an error when I try to run the below code:

> The variable name '@NoOfDays' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

As you can see, I need to use this variable twice. If I add `Declare @NoOfDays int` at the beginning, powergadgets just crashes. I am pretty new to SQL, but in the past using a user-passed variable twice has never caused problems. What can I do to resolve the issue?

```
SELECT        
    a.resolved, b.opened, 
    a.weekClosed AS week, 
    a.yearClosed AS year, 
    CAST(a.yearClosed as varchar(5)) + ', ' + CAST(a.weekClosed as varchar(5)) AS period
FROM            
    (SELECT        
         TOP (100) PERCENT COUNT(DISTINCT TicketNbr) AS resolved,
         { fn WEEK(date_closed) } AS weekClosed,
         { fn YEAR(date_closed) } AS yearClosed
     FROM v_rpt_Service
     WHERE        
         (date_closed >= DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()) - @NoOfDays, 0))
     GROUP BY 
         { fn WEEK(date_closed) }, { fn YEAR(date_closed) }
    ) AS  a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
         COUNT(DISTINCT TicketNbr) AS opened, 
         { fn WEEK(date_entered) } AS weekEntered,
         { fn YEAR(date_entered) } AS yearEntered
     FROM 
         v_rpt_Service AS v_rpt_Service_1
     WHERE        
         (date_entered > = DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()) - @NoOfDays, 0))
     GROUP BY 
         { fn WEEK(date_entered) }, { fn YEAR(date_entered) }
    ) AS b ON a.weekClosed = b.weekEntered AND a.yearClosed = b.yearEntered
ORDER BY 
    year, week
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug within Powergadgets, and the way it wraps queries. to me.  It is examining the query, seeing two searches, each with a required variable, and then tries creating them as parameters.  Hence you get the duplicate declaration error.

Suggestion - change the variable name in the second query, and then pass the value in twice (essentially creating two parameters).  If it works, then we know that Powergadgets has a problem with variables being used twice in slightly different scope.

Comment: That's what I am doing now to get around it. However, my boss doesn't really like having to enter the same number twice every time. Is there nothing I can do about it?

Comment: Assuming that PG doesn't have a problem with you declaring local variables in your code (you mentioned it caused a crash above) you could pass one parameter, declare two local variables, and set them both equal to the value of the parameter.

Comment: If it DOES have a problem with you creating local variables, then I suggest you use a different product :).  In any case, you need to address yourself to PG and their support structure - this is not a TSQL problem.  Good luck.

Comment: I tried that, if I declare two local variables and then set them to my passed one, it tells me I have to declare the scalar variable. If I declare all three, it crashes.

Answer (score 4):

Show your entire code and the problem should become apparent.

The issue is not that you are referencing the variable twice, it's that you are **DECLARING** it twice.  In a session you can only have one variable of a given name, and there is no way to drop them manually.

Either you are running multiple batches per session and the variable is carrying over between queries, or you are declaring it twice in your actual code (which is not displayed).

Comment: @PRNDLDevelopmentStudios - then how is the variable being declared?  Is this a stored procedure with a parameter?

Comment: In the box that says "SQL Statement" I am typing literally what is above. As I said, I am new to SQL, but it throws me errors to use a DECLARE statement, but just calling a variable name it asks the user to supply a value.

Comment: @PRNDLDevelopmentStudios - so this is from within powergadgets? Is there a spot to declar your variables in the framework you are using?

Comment: Correct, and no it creates the variables based on the query.

Comment: @PRNDLDevelopmentStudios then how do you give them values?

Comment: When the product is run, it prompts the user to enter the values.

Comment: @PRNDLDevelopmentStudios - then I would consider using a different product or submitting a bug report with a high priority for this.  Not being able to handle the same variable twice is kind of a **HUGE** oversight in the design of this tool.